# MVC3 validation problems

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have the following view, which fails to validate on  Title, and NewsContent. Title validation works but not NewsContent. How can i fix it.

```
@model Foo.NewsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}



@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "News", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Category Information</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.News.Title)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.News.Title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.News.Title)
            </div>
               <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.News.NewsContent)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field" id="container">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.News.NewsContent)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.News.NewsContent)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.News.Thumbnail)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="file" name="files" id="thumbnail" />
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.News.Image)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="file" name="files" id="original" />
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("SelectedCategoryId")
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategoryId, Model.Categories)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                Publish
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.News.Published, new { @checked = "checked" })
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

and here is the model|:

```
 public class News : IStorable
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Content")]
        public virtual string NewsContent { set; get; }
......
```

Comment: is news content RichText area like FCKEditor etc.

Comment: it s just textarea right now bt i ll add wysiwyg

Comment: which Entity Framework 'flavor' are you using?

Comment: how is it related to Entity Framework/

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is not working? "Title validation works but not NewsContent" so this means `Title` is required but you can submit the form without filling in `NewsContent` or something else is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue: Title validation works but not NewsContent.

Validations is not work, because of using Html.TextAreaFor() helper to render the "NewsContent" property,

Here is the code to make it work:

Change your model as:

Decorate the 'NewsContent' property with [DataType] attribute and set the data type as 'MultilineText'. This will indicates that the editor for this property should be a multi-line text input.

```
public class News : IStorable
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Title")]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "Content")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public virtual string NewsContent { set; get; }
    //....
}
```

In the view use Html.EditorFor() helper instead of Html.TextAreaFor() for the 'News.NewsContent' property.

```
//....
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.News.NewsContent)
</div>

<div class="editor-field" id="container">

    @*@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.News.NewsContent)*@

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.News.NewsContent)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.News.NewsContent)
</div>
//....
```